# Do all packages get upgraded with sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, software-center, software-sources

In the software manager, reviews often complain about how the packages are out of date. But can't you upgrade the packages using `sudo apt upgrade` and `sudo apt update`?

Comment: Most of the reviews are about the **versions of the package present** in the repositories.  This is explained in https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? Also where are you seeing reviews often complain about how the packages are out of date

Comment: Thanks for the link.

Comment: Well, mint 20.1, but on a few. Kdenlive, and playon linux to name a few

Answer (score 2):

No. `apt upgrade` only installs updates to packages that are already installed; it will not add new dependencies.

The command you want is `apt full-upgrade` which will also install updates that have dependences that are not already present.